# SharePoint cannot edit Metadata until edited in Word

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office

I am working with a SharePoint Foundation installation where thousands of documents will be migrated into a specific site.  After migration on a few test libraries occur, we have document library with metadata pulled from migration logs.  When user edits a document properties in modal dialog (occurs more with Word than with PDF files) and user clicks save, metadata is not updated in SharePoint library.  If user selects document and chooses to "Edit in Microsoft Word" metadata is pulled into Word document properties.  So metadata is being updated but not reflected back into document library.

I did additional tests where I update metadata within Word itself and the metadata in columns updates correctly.  After this metadata can be updated freely in modal dialog box within SharePoint.

Anyone have ideas why users cannot update metadata until edited within Word?

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b9xP.png)

Comment: do you have any customizations within SharePoint? Any javascript/jquery (those are usually the culprit)? What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 8 in a XP environment. There is no javascript attached to the document library that I or the SharePoint Admin sees.  Beyond basic branding for the site and use of a custom content type for this particular library, there is no customization of SharePoint.

Comment: can you improve your screenshots? I can't see them well..

Answer (score 2):

I am particularly interested in this question. Here is my situation:

1. a SharePoint document library with custom fields: Discipline, DocumentType, EnnineeringActivityCode, OriginatorSourceCode
2. When uploading a Word document for the first time with these fields in the Custom properites section for the document, the metadata values ARE added to the SharePoint library fields.
3. Once the document is in the library and I choose Edit in Microsoft Word I edit the document AND update the metadata vlaues in the Custom properties section.
4. The SharePoint library values are NOT updated.

Juan, Mike... any further information you require or information to share?

Cheers
David